# socket.io not allowing clearInterval to work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, setinterval

I want to call clearInterval from another socket.emit function. However, due to some reason it is not allowing me to cancel the function.

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on('compute', message => {
        const intervalID = setInterval(() => computeFunction(message.data, socket, intervalID), 100);
    });
    socket.on('erase', message) => {
        clearInterval(message.id);
    }
 });
 
 computeFunction(data, socket, id) {
    socket.emit('delete', id);
 }
```

Comment: What is the server sending along with `erase`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're emitting only the ID, and when you handle the `erase` event, you expect an object (`message.id`).

Try emitting an object along with the `delete` event:

```
socket.emit('delete', {id}); // send an object {id: [socket id]}
```

Also, the `computeFunction` doesn't seem to use the `data` parameter.

Hope this helps.